# How to properly create a HeatMap with Bokeh

Tags: python, heatmap, bokeh

I'm trying to replicate the HeatMap shown in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14391959/heatmap-in-matplotlib-with-pcolor) using Bokeh instead of matplotlib. I can't get it quite right though. The existing examples have not helped me to understand what I'm doing wrong. My humble attempt

```
from bokeh.io import output_notebook; output_notebook()
from bokeh.charts import HeatMap, show
from bokeh.palettes import RdYlGn6
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

nba = pd.read_csv(urlopen("http://datasets.flowingdata.com/ppg2008.csv"), index_col=0)

# Normalize the data columns and sort.
nba = (nba - nba.mean()) / (nba.max() - nba.min())
nba.sort('PTS', inplace=True)

score = []
for x in nba.apply(tuple):
  score.extend(x)

data = {
  'players': list(nba.index) * len(nba.columns),
  'metric':  list(nba.columns) * len(nba.index),
  'score':   score,
}

hm = HeatMap(data, x='metric', y='players',values='score', title='Fruits', stat=None)
show(hm)
```

Gives

[image]

Note that, despite the similar title, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35189203/bokeh-heatmap-usage) does not answer my question. It's not the same error and I'm using Bokeh 0.12.3

Comment: The data aren't lined up correctly.  You've repeated both `players` and `metric` list-wise, one of them needs to be repeated element-wise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the generation of the data `metric` to repeat element-wise and it should be correct:

```
'metric': [item for item in list(nba.columns) for i in range(len(nba.index))],
```

So the code that works for me is the following:

```
from bokeh.charts import HeatMap, show, output_file
import pandas as pd, numpy as np
from urllib2 import urlopen

nba = pd.read_csv(urlopen("http://datasets.flowingdata.com/ppg2008.csv"), index_col=0)

# Normalize the data columns and sort.
nba = (nba - nba.mean()) / (nba.max() - nba.min())
nba.sort_values(by = 'PTS', inplace=True)

score = []
for x in nba.apply(tuple):
  score.extend(x)

data = {
  'players': list(nba.index) * len(nba.columns),
  'metric':  [item for item in list(nba.columns) for i in range(len(nba.index))],
  'score':   score,
}

output_file('test.html')
hm = HeatMap(data, x='metric', y='players',values='score', title='Fruits', stat=None)
show(hm)
```

[image]

Comment: Ah, of course! Thanks! :-) Just as a side note, `list(nba.index)` is not necessary, at least here it works wihout.

Answer (score 14):

In case you still want to create a heatmap using Bokeh: the charts module was removed in more recent versions. In other words, this command will not work with newer versions of Bokeh:

```
from bokeh.charts import HeatMap
```

Since it gives the error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'charts'
```

Charts was moved to bkcharts package, which was than discontinued (further reference in [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48170086/what-to-use-instead-of-bokeh-charts)). Holoviews still has some support for Bokeh, but has some different syntax.

A solution for creating Heatmaps in Bokeh is using p.rect() as instructed in [this link about unemployment.py](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/gallery/unemployment.html), which results in something like this:

```
p = figure()
hm = p.rect(data, x='metric', y='players',values='score', title='Fruits', stat=None)
```

Which yields a results that looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Note that the `values=` kwarg does not exist anymore since at least version `1.4.0`. In the updated "unemployment" example, a `LinearColorMapper` is used instead.