# Pandas related error when generating heatmap with Bokeh

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, bokeh

I'm trying to reproduce this [heatmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41282592/how-to-properly-create-a-heatmap-with-bokeh) but I keep getting the following error:

> AttributeError: 'pandas._libs.interval.Interval' object has no attribute 'split'

I'm running pandas version 0.20.2 and bokeh version 0.12.5.

I've found someone who has the same issue in this [post](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/4743) but wasn't able to find a fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently this is a known issue due to recent changes made to pandas. Running pandas version before 0.20 gets rid of the error.